# How to return an array more efficiently

Tags: go

My requirements is to have a function to return an array efficiently.

As I know, array is value type, so when passing in/out array to a function, it does `copy`. Therefore, I am thinking return pointer of array. People will recommend using slice, but by using slice, I still need `copy` to transfer to array.

[This](https://play.golang.org/p/-CZ6_zvh6rG) is the playground contains both solutions, please suggest if it is right way to go to return pointer of array, thanks.

```
package main

import (
 "fmt"
)

type geo [2]float32

func genArray () geo {
  ret := geo{1.2, 2.3}
  return ret
}

func genPointerOfArray () *geo {
  ret := geo{1.2, 2.3}
  return &ret
}


func main() {
  ret1 := genArray()
  ret2 := *genPointerOfArray()
  fmt.Println(ret1, ret2)
}
```

Comment: Is this example true to your real code? If so, don't worry about an array of length two. You wouldn't think twice about passing two float32 arguments to a function either, would you?

Comment: slice doesn't contain array, it contains pointer to array. which means you are indirectly copying pointer of array. If you want to make changes to array then you need to use pointer.

Comment: @Peter, it is not my real code, the real one is like [256]byte. In this case do you think it is ok passing by array?

Comment: @nilsocket, so you mean slice actually will move and copy around in heap, even it     doesn't expand?  And do you imply that it is ok to return pointer of array? Thanks.

Comment: @Ron, 256 bytes isn't much data in most cases, but may be a lot on really hot code paths. I suggest you [profile](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/) to find out if it matters for you. If you use slices the underlaying array isn't copied (that's why they were  recommended). For details see https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: @Ron you need not to worry about returning a pointer to an array. That's why slices are used which is a pointer to an underlying bootstrap array. In that case you can easily provide the length and capacity for a slice which will let you not even change the slice header to another array in case your slice grows more than the capacity.

Comment: @Peter @Himanshu, I want to use slice, but in my case, I declare `[256]byte` in one field of my struct. I can change `[256]byte` to slice(`[]byte`), but by doing that it actually lost the length constraints I want to apply.

Comment: @Ron Please recreate the problem again with all the constraints you are saying. Along with that if you want a length constraint. By default using a slice is again good because it will create a pointer to the array with the exact length.

Comment: This is a classic example of premature optimisation. Until a CPU profile with a production-like workload shows that returning data here is the most important or last remaining bottleneck all such microoptimisations are wasted time. It might even be **faster** to copy these 256 bytes than passing pointers and nonbody can tell because it depends so much on memory access pattern and memory layout (NUMA) and cache usage and and and. Stop doing such useless work.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- Why do you think this is inefficient? Is it just a hunch, or do you have some benchmark telling you so?

Comment: Unless you have measurements showing that passing this data by value is a problem, do what's easiest to work with and don't try to make it "more efficient" unless you need to. Also keep in mind that copying isn't inherently more efficient than passing a pointer (which puts the value under scope of garbage collection).

Answer (score 8):

### Arrays and Slices in Golang

Most people who start to learn Go understand the concept of a slice. It's a lightweight wrapper around an array which can, but doesn't necessarily have to, represent a subset (or slice) of that underlying array. Despite this understanding, developers continue to get tripped up when putting that knowledge to practice. Why?

The problem arises when you want to pass an array to a function. Go's documentation makes it clear that arrays are passed by copy. Useful perhaps, if you want the array to be immutable. In most cases though, it's simply an inefficiency. Initially, you might be tempted to do something like:

```
names := []string{"leto", "paul", "teg"}
process(&names)

func process(names *[]string) {
  ...
}
```

That might set off your spidey sense. So you head off to the golang-nuts user group, read relevant posts, or maybe ask a question, and the answer you inevitably get back is: don't pass arrays, pass slices.

That kinda fits with what you know, since slices are thin wrappers around arrays. But still, this only feels marginally better:

```
names := []string{"leto", "paul", "teg"}
process(names[0:])

func process(names []string) {
  ...
}
```

You think to yourself, Who are these people who only ever deal with slices of arrays? 95% of the time, I need all the data in the array, not just part of it!

And here, we get to the two fundamental misconceptions people have when they think about arrays and slices.

First, think of a slices ability to represent part of the underlying array as a secondary benefit. First and foremost, a slice is a reference to an array. A slice which represents the entire array is extremely common. The second point makes this much more absolute.

Second, you are almost certainly already dealing with a slice. names above, is already a slice (which covers the entire underlying array). The only time you're dealing with an array is when you create it with a size:

```
  names := [3]string{"leto", "paul", "teg"}
  //or
  names := [3]string{}
```

Everything else, is a slice:

```
  names := []string{"leto", "paul", "teg"}
  //or
  names := make([]string, 3)
  //or
  var names []string
```

So, the solution to the above code ends up being the most intuitive:

```
   names := []string{"leto", "paul", "teg"}
    process(names)

    func process(names []string) {
      ...
    }
```

Let's take this a step further and use this knowledge to clarify another common issue. Should you create an array of pointers. For example, which is better?

```
  sayans := []*Sayan{
    &Sayan{Name: "Goku", Power: 9001,}
  }
  //or
  sayans := []Sayan{
    Sayan{Name: "Goku", Power: 9001,}
  }
```

In both cases, sayans is a slice. Therefore, when it comes to passing this to a function (or returning it), they are the same. Whether or not the extra indirection provided by the first example is useful depends on the situation, but if you aren't sure, it probably isn't, and you should be using the 2nd version.

The two important points are:

> Slices are references to arrays which happen to have to ability to
>   represent a subset, and Almost everything is already a slice

Comment: I'm sorry, not native speaker, which one is better, return `[]interface{}` or return `*[]interface{}` out of function?

Comment: @http8086 reiterating what was written, if you're not sure then just use `[]interface`